# Copy one xls's all sheets to another xls file using macro vba via customized button designed on sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, xls

I have one file of xls and it contains 15 sheets data and I want to copy all data to my another xls file. I have so many files like this so I want to make it customized using macro vba coding. I want to design button on first sheet which do run macro code and copy all my sheets to another file.So is it possible? I am not aware more about ms office.Would any one share me guideline,link or any related data for this.
Thank you all

Comment: I want functionality as describe below link  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/copy_range.php     But this is only for sheet to sheet copy and I want to copy one xls file to another xls file.

Comment: Are you compiling all the sheets together (i.e. sheets from multiple xl files go into a single xl file)? If you're just directly copying (i.e. 3 sheets in A.xls to 3 sheets in B.xls), then why not just copy the file itself? That said, you could create a macro that takes all the xl workbooks in a folder and saves them as new files (copy with new names) which would automate the manual copying. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Zairja  I have two xls file one is employee.xls and another is dept.xls Now I have created button in which i want to put macro vba code which makes copy of my employee.xls'sheet1 into dept.xls sheet1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes both files are open and runs from the dept.xls since that seems to be the one you are preserving.

```
Sub emp_to_dept()

Dim wks As Worksheet
    Windows("Employees.xls").Activate
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Copy After:=Workbooks("Dept.xls").Sheets(1)
    Next
    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @sinh99 Also, keep in mind that unless you save the workbook as .xlb or .xlsm, then you will have to reenter this code every time.

Comment: good observation @sinh99, this will work in excel 2003 but later versions will require the different extensions